# For how long has Lorcan been frozen at the age 17?

Tags: vampirates

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and have already tried another website but found nothing, **for how long has Lorcan Furey been frozen at the age of 17?**

Comment: What other site(s) have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

### Nearly 700 years.

From book 3, *Blood Captain*:

> "My name," he said, "is Lorcan Furey." Grace watched him intently as he continued. "Born 1803 in Connemara, died 1820 in Dublin."

So he's been stuck at seventeen years old ever since 1820. Given that the book is set in the early 2500s, this means he's been 'frozen', as you put it, for nearly 700 years.